# Program stops parsing when last position of string is punctuation

Tags: c++, string, parsing, iterator

So I'm trying to read all words from a file, and get rid of the punctuation as I do that. Here is the logic that is stripping the punctuation:

Edit: The program actually stops running altogether, just want to make that clear

```
ifstream file("text.txt");

string              str;
string::iterator    cur;

for(file>>str; !file.eof(); file>>str){
    for(cur = str.begin(); cur != str.end(); cur++){
         if (!(isalnum(*cur))){
            cur = str.erase(cur);
         }
    }
cout << str << endl;
...
}
```

Say I have a text file that reads:

```
This is a program. It has trouble with (non alphanumeric chars)

But it's my own and I love it...
```

When I `cout` and `endl;` my string right after this bit of logic, I'll get

```
This
is
a
program
It
has
trouble
with
non
alphanumeric
```

and that's all folks.
Is there something wrong with my iterator logic?
How could I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I accidentally clicked to edit the last person's comment and it got lost. I apologize.

Comment: he probably decided to remove it himself, it's ok

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using gcc 4.6.3, not sure if I have access to regex or not. Eclipse isn't compiling it.

Comment: How are newlines getting into the string? I don't see it in your code, also it doesn't really compile due to `cur` being undefined, are you showing your actual code?

Comment: `File>>string` and an iteration of that.

Comment: still, how have newlines got between the words of the first string, i.e. immediately after the word "This" in the sample output?

Comment: ^Added to the code I have there. Was just trying to show what I thought was the problem.

Comment: No, it's not there, the provided code will output something like "Thisisaprogram" etc

Comment: I can assure you `cout << str << endl;` will output one string per line.

Comment: yes, but in your example you get like **10** lines of output for 3 lines of input, so where are all these newlines coming from?

Comment: From my understand, and how I'm using it, `file>>string` will pass in everything in between white space or newlines, regardless of how far apart they are. It's worked for me.

Comment: ohoh, sorry, I had just woke up when I asked this. This makes sense indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main logical problem with iterators I see is that for non-alphanumeric characters the iterator gets increased twice: during `erase` it moves to the next symbol and then `cur++` from the `for` loop increases it, so it skips every symbol after a non-alphanumeric one.

So probably something along the lines of:

```
string              next;
string::iterator    cur;

cur = next.begin()
while(cur != next.end()){
    if (!(isalnum(*cur))){
        cur = next.erase(cur);
    } else {
        cur++;
    }
}
```

This just removes the non-alphanumeric characters. If you need to tokenize your input, you will have to implement a bit more, i.e. remember, whether you're inside a word (have read at least one alphanumeric character) or not and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

How about just not copying *in* the punctuation when building the transformed list. OK. probably overkill.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

// takes the file being processed as only command line param
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    vector<string> res;
    std::transform(istream_iterator<string>(inf),
        istream_iterator<string>(),
        back_inserter(res),
        [](const string& s) {
            string tmp; copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(tmp),
            [](char c) { return std::isalnum(c); });
            return tmp;
        });

    // optional dump to output
    copy(res.begin(), res.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Input**

```
All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players:
They have their exits and their entrances;
And one man in his time plays many parts,
His acts being seven ages. At first, the infant,
Mewling and puking in the nurse's arms.
```

**Output**

```
All
the
worlds
a
stage
And
all
the
men
and
women
merely
players
They
have
their
exits
and
their
entrances
And
one
man
in
his
time
plays
many
parts
His
acts
being
seven
ages
At
first
the
infant
Mewling
and
puking
in
the
nurses
arms
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the bit of poetry.

Comment: Stay tuned for my next question as I fumble around trying to get my `map` to keep a word frequency count to work!

Comment: @nzondlo the above code with a little massaging makes that trivial as well, just fyi. remember this: `++mymap[str];`, where `mymap` is a `std::map<string, unsigned int>`. It will come to when you start coding your next task.

Comment: Thanks, I had something similar. It's printing the darn thing is where I'm having trouble.

Comment: @nzondlo See [this sample for an update](http://ideone.com/joKNbx). I took the liberty of lower-casing all the words as well. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ispunct` to test for a punctuation character. If you also want to filter out control characters you should use `iscntrl`.

Once you've filtered out the punctutation you can split a spaces and newlines to get the words.